# Regex modification needed to enforce atleast one special symbol character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex for a password field :

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,63}$/
```

I'd like to enhance it to force atleast one number , one alphabet and one special  symbol.

I'm using the following JavaScript code to validate the same :

```
function validatePassword()
{

    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var userID = document.getElementById('user_ID').value;
    var regexPattern = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,63}$/ ;

    if(regexPattern.test(password))
    {

        if(userID === password )
        {
            $('#status').text( 'User id is same as password . Please choose a more secure password');

            return false;
        }

        else if(password === reverse(userID))
        {
            $('#status').text( 'Password is reverse of user id . Please choose a more secure password');

            return false;
        }

        else
        {
        return true;
        }


        }
    else

        {
        return false;
        }
}
```

How do I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: [That regex works](https://regex101.com/r/bP2cP6/1)

Comment: `(?=.*\d)` enforces 1 digit. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` enforces 1 alphabet letter. `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])` enforces at least 1 special character. `[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()_+]{7,63}` allows 8 to 64 characters starting with a letter or digit. Now, what are your requirements?

Comment: My requirement is that all of the 3 character types [alpha-numeric & special characters ] must be present in an entered value. 

Currently , on providing input a password like 12345678 , I'm able to insert a record into the database .

Comment: The function [works](https://jsfiddle.net/ez64s55y/) well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex you can check like this also.

Just replace

```
if(regexPattern.test(password))
```

with

```
if(regexPattern.test(password) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(password) && /[0-9]/.test(password) && /[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]/.test(password) )
```

Check string if it is valid password, contain alphabet, number and special character ( if you want more add in range ).